# Ag-grid: Data Size Limitation for Enterprise license

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am integrating ag-grid in my product and wondering if anyone has done stress testing of ag-grid to see the limits of # of rows/#of columns (or file size) can break ag-grid?

Comment: There are different row models to support larger amounts of data: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-viewport/?framework=all#gsc.tab=0 / https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-enterprise-model/?framework=all#gsc.tab=0. The main demo shows "100,000 rows, 22 cols" if you change the "data size": https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php.

Answer (score 0):

Both the free and enterprise versions will take the same amount of data - the limiting factor will be your users browsers, not the grid itself.

The grid (by default) will only render what's displayed so really the only limiting factor will be the memory available in your users browser.

Practically we've found you'll almost certainly want to use a row model (infinite for example) or pagination for truly vast amounts of data as it simply isn't useful for a user to have massive amounts of data within the grid for user consumption.